# How to access the complete string of a dtype object in a dataframe?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I am doing some webscraping (getting the plot of books on goodreads). I have this info in a tsv file. When i get that tsv file into a dataframe it looks like i loose the best part of my string. How can i access the whole string?
Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `data['Plot']` is returning a Series with 1 element (not the element itself). Much like having a list with one element you need to tell pandas to return the first element in that series.

To do this you can write:

```py
data['plot'].iloc[0]
```